# Ember.js How to avoid infinite loop in computed properties?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have this controller. It reads `publishedAt` from a model and separates into date and time like this:

```
dd: function() {
    console.log('dd');
    return moment(this.get('publishedAt')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}.property('publishedAt'),

tt: function() {
    console.log('tt');
    return moment(this.get('publishedAt')).format('H:m');
}.property('publishedAt'),

// check for recursion
publishedAt: function() {
    console.log('publishedAt');
    return moment(this.get('dd') + this.get('tt')).toDate();
}.property('dd', 'tt'),
```

As you can see, it separates the `publishedAt` into date and time and when there is a change in either date or time, it updates the final `publishedAt`.

Now this is my big problem... It produces an infinite loop getting each other's value. How to solve this? Please help.

Comment: Which one do you actually care about? dd, tt or publishedAt?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually need the publishedAt as it will be saved/taken to/from the database. dd and tt are for the input boxes..

Answer (score 0):

```
dd: function() { // in the controller
    console.log('dd');
    return moment(this.get('publishedAt')).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // from the model
}.property('publishedAt'),

tt: function() { // in the controller
    console.log('tt');
    return moment(this.get('publishedAt')).format('H:m'); // from the model
}.property('publishedAt'),

// check for recursion, in the controller
publishedAtDisplay: function() {
    console.log('publishedAtDisplay');
    return moment(this.get('dd') + this.get('tt')).toDate();
}.property('dd', 'tt'),
```

Comment: How to save publishedAt back to the database?